# Obtaining stack frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack-trace

How do I get a stack frame to pass into `traceback.print_stack`?

From [Python 3.3a1 docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/traceback.html?highlight=print_stack#traceback.print_stack):

> `traceback.print_stack(f=None, limit=None, file=None)`
>
> This function
>   prints a stack trace from its invocation point. The optional `f`
>   argument can be used to specify an alternate **stack frame** to start. The
>   optional limit and file arguments have the same meaning as for
>   `print_exception()`.

But nowhere in the docs did I find a way to actually obtain a stack frame. To be specific, let's say I want to print the stack trace starting one level above the invocation point. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`inspect.stack()` will get you the current stack as a list. You can pick any frame you want out of it. You can also do e.g. `inspect.currentframe().f_back` to get your caller's frame.  Basically, the `inspect` module is where it's at.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) documentation gives information on functions you could use to get a stack frame, for example `inspect.currentframe()`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to inspect module, you can try:

```
import sys
sys._getframe(1)
```

or

```
import sys
sys._getframe().f_back
```

Be warned it is a private function, some versions of python may not implement it.